# Safari force page scroll position to top failed when page refresh

Tags: scroll, mobile-safari, page-refresh

I am building a website using react to implement.First, we scroll the page to the bottom or middle position.Then we click refresh button in the iphone safari browser，page scroll to the permanent position strangely.I have tried to change the  flex layout to float layout and add pageshow event listener to set scrollTop zero using

> window.scrollTo(0,0)

.But page still stop at the permanent position in safari mobile.

I guess the problem is the page save the position of last view, but when page fresh, the content of the page is not show completely, and then the page could only scroll to the permanent position.At last, the rest part of the page show out.And the pageshow event has been triggered early before the page scroll to the permanent position.
How can I force the page to be scrolled to the top on page refresh except window.scroll? How can I solve this strange behavior of the safari browser?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue as you using react on ios safari, the only fixed I found is to use a setTimeout in `componentDidMount`, but I really don't like this solution

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 800); 
}
```

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

use window.scroll(0, 0) instead of window.scrollTo()